# Bivariate-Normal Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

$X$ and $Y$ are iid standard normal random variables. Assume $a, b, c, d$ and $u$ are constants. Calculate $E( cX + dY | aX + bY = u)$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{align*}
\beta = \frac{ac+bd}{a^2+b^2}.
\end{align*}
Then $cX+dY - \beta(aX+bY)$ and $aX+bY$ are independent.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E( cX + dY \mid aX + bY = u)= \beta u.
\end{align*}